# How to call UL class only once using domdocument php

Tags: php, html

I am using PHP Domdocument to load my html. In my HTML, I have class="smalllist" two times. But, I need to load the first class elements.

Now, My PHP Code is

```
    $d = new DOMDocument();
    $d->validateOnParse = true;
    @$d->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($d);
    $table = $xpath->query('//ul[@class="smalllist"]');
    foreach ($table as $row) {
       echo $row->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->nodeValue."-";
       echo $row->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(1)->nodeValue."\n";

    }
```

which loads both the classes. 
But, I need to load only one class with that name.
Please help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my final code:

```
        $d = new DOMDocument();
        $d->validateOnParse = true;
        @$d->loadHTML($html);
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($d);
        $table = $xpath->query('//ul[@class="smalllist"]');
        $count = 0;
        foreach($table->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('a') as $anchor){
           $data[$k][$arr1[$count]] = $anchor->nodeValue;
           if( ++$count > 1 ) {
              break;
           }
        }
```

Working fine.

Answer (score 0):

`DOMXPath` returns a `DOMNodeList` which has a `item()` method. see if this works

```
$table->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->nodeValue
```

edited (untested):

```
foreach($table->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('a') as $anchor){
  echo $anchor->nodeValue . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Gwillie, thanks! this is working fine. Now, I am facing some small problem. Here I again have 4 <a> element values. But, I need only first two of them and the remaining two are not required.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a `break` within the `foreach` loop to read only from the first class. Or, you can do `foreach ($table->item(0) as $row) {`...

**Code:**

```
$count = 0;
foreach($table->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('a') as $anchor){
   echo $anchor->nodeValue . "\n";
   if( ++$count > 2 ) {
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thats not working. Means, it doesnt give any result.

Comment: foreach($table->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('a') as $anchor){
            echo $anchor->nodeValue . "\n";
        }

Comment: This is the modified and working code.Here, I am having 4 anchor tags. But, I need only first two.

Comment: That was ok. But, i need to store data like array([0]['url'=>'www.ex.com','country'=>'india'][1]['url'=>'www.ex1.com','country'=>'india']) so, i need the first two values in two variables. like $url = $anchor->nodeValue; $country = $anchor->nodeValue2; is this possible. Please check and tell me

Answer (score 0):

another way rather than using break (more than one way to skin a cat):

```
$anchors = $table->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('a');
for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++){
  echo $anchor->item($i)->nodeValue . "\n";
}
```